# Cyclically shifting a colormap

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to cyclically shift e.g. the hsv colormap so that the central color can be altered? It's taking up quite some space in my figure, and I'd like it to be a different color. As the colormap is cyclical, this should be possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the non-linear colormap used in this [example](http://protracted-matter.blogspot.co.nz/2012/08/nonlinear-colormap-in-matplotlib.html), but with linear levels replaces by a shift,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

class roll_cmap(LinearSegmentedColormap):

    def __init__(self, cmap, shift):

        assert 0. < shift < 1.
        self.cmap = cmap
        self.N = cmap.N
        self.monochrome = self.cmap.monochrome
        self._x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 255)
        self._y = np.roll(np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 255),int(255.*shift))

    def __call__(self, xi, alpha=1.0, **kw):
        yi = np.interp(xi, self._x, self._y)
        return self.cmap(yi, alpha)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    y, x = np.mgrid[0.0:3.0:100j, 0.0:5.0:100j]
    H = np.sin(8*x/np.pi)

    cmap = plt.cm.hsv
    cmap_rolled = roll_cmap(cmap, shift=0.8)

    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.contourf(x, y, H, cmap=cmap)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.contourf(x, y, H, cmap=cmap_rolled)
    plt.colorbar()

    plt.show()
```

which results in the following output,

[image]