# Cyclically shifting a colormap with cartopy projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, cartopy

I would like to plot geophysical variables using shifted cyclic color map (e.g. a shifted version of `matplotlib.pyplot.cm.twilight`).

A similar question was asked and correctly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736503/cyclically-shifting-a-colormap). However, I found that the solutions does not work for caropty projections, which is essential to me because of the nature of my data.

Following script will throw an error:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

lons = range(359)
lats = range(-89,89)
data = np.random.randn(len(lats),len(lons))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap=shifted_cmap)
```

Using `shifted_cmap` from the first solution instead of any other standard color map (e.g. like `'twilight'`) results in the following error:

```py
AttributeError: 'roll_cmap' object has no attribute '_rgba_bad'
```

To be honest, I have no clue what's going on. Thought in the beginning it was due to `NaN` in my data, but even this easy example doesn't work. However, the error only occurs if I specify `projection` in `fig.add_subplot()`.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Does this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65018952/8881141) help?

Comment: Thanks! @Mr.T, the solutions of that post indeed solved my problem. Perhaps moderator can refer to this as an DUPLICATE and point to the solution?